# Changing JProgressBar

Tags: java, swing, jprogressbar

After noticing this link:
http://www.newscientist.com/blogs/nstv/2010/12/best-videos-of-2010-progress-bar-illusion.html
I wanted to make my jprogressbar look like that. How would I go about doing that? Is there a library that already does that for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer - create a custom [ProgressBarUI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/ProgressBarUI.html) (overload [BasicProgressBar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicProgressBarUI.html) for easiest use) and override the paintDeterminate method.

Longer answer - I'm in middle of experimenting exactly how you'd do this, will create a blog post with source code and link back to it here.

Edit:  I have it working now.  Here's a [sample video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f_hwisvBQEc)

Code is available [on github](https://github.com/I82Much/animated-progressbar-ui)

Blog post to follow.

Comment: Thanks, that would be much appreciated. I wouldn't know what to put in the paintDeterminate method even if i overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the video is unavailable, second is an illusion, is like the bar of Vista and 7, since it has an animation that makes it look like it's advancing, when it's not, you could try to recreate the Vista o 7, progress bar on Java.

If you find the video working, again, we can think on a way to re-create it

Comment: I just clicked the link and the video worked for me (after a small delay on firefox). It is an illusion but after hearing some of the superficial complaints from certain clients, this illusion will definitely work for them. Also, how do I get the vista progress bar (which I've never seen before Btw) in Java?

Comment: Or you make your own from scratch, or use the opposite of swing ( can't remember the name right now)

Comment: Link worked for me in Chrome, (delay my have been an illusion).

Comment: I'm currently at work, and maybe the net, has it's limits, i'll check it out at home, and then i'll late you know